# Why doesn't V-model update data on autofill in Edge using Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, input, autofill

V-model doesn't update data on autofill (Edge) forms/inputs untill user clicks somewhere

```
const isActive = ref<boolean>()
const inputData = ref<string>('')
 <label :class="isActive ? 'label-active' : 'label'" for="emailfield">{{ props.name }}</label>
  <input

:class="props.background ? 'background' : ''"
    :type="props.type"
    v-model="inputData"
   :value="inputData"
    @focusout="inputData === '' ? (isActive = false) : (isActive = true)"
    :name="props.nameInput"
    @change="inputData === '' ? (isActive = false) : (isActive = true)"
    @focusin="isActive = true"
    :is-active="isActive"
    :autocomplete="props.type"
    id="emailfield"
    minlength="5"
    maxlength="50"
  />
```

Tried adding @change adding watch and using onMounted

Answer (score 1):

That is how the change event works on text inputs in standard HTML

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

> Depending on the kind of element being changed and the way the user interacts with the element, the change event fires at a different moment:
>
> - When the element loses focus after its value was changed: for elements where the user's interaction is typing rather than selection, such as a `<textarea>` or the `text`, `search`, `url`, `tel`, `email`, or `password` types of the `<input>` element.

What you probably want to use is the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event which fires as soon as the text value is changed.